# Accidentally deleted all boot options on my laptop. What next?

Tags: boot, bootloader, bootable-media

I accidentally deleted every boot entry on my laptop. I cannot boot from USB. It doesn't boot anything useful by default. There are no options for selecting what to boot or boot priority. I think I did it with `efibootmgr`.

What can I do to fix this?

I think I did it with `efibootmgr`. That includes booting from USB. When it boots normally it goes to a thing where I select what to boot, but as I deleted every entry, it's empty. It lets me go to setup (From bootloader and by pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> on startup) where I can change the boot order of nothing. I don't know how to get to BIOS (or even really know what BIOS is).

There's an <kbd>F4</kbd> option that says for recovery, but it does nothing when I press it. I am completely befuddled and discombobulated as to what to do now as I really don't know what I'm doing.

I have an HDD and an SSD built-in to the machine. I have GRUB installed on partition 1 of the SSD, but I can't start it, as it isn't listed as an option to boot.

Comment: Can you get into BIOS?  If so, reset it to default and see if the BIOS options return.

Comment: Please explain what you mean when you say you deleted all boot options? Did you edit your GRUB config to remove everything? Did you enter BIOS and disable them? Please also list what the boot options where.

Comment: @music2myear The booting options the... Well I think it's the BIOS, boots from. As in, where the EFI file for GRUB is, it forgot that (and USB, etc)

Comment: @John I hardly know what BIOS is, do you mean the setup it lets me do if I press F2 in POST(?)(Could be some completely different phase)? Or is it a command line? I cannot find a way to get a command line.

Comment: Yes, it's most likely that thing you access with F2. What's your laptop's model? How have you removed all boot options? Please add this information using the [edit] button.

Comment: @gronostaj I just changed it to say I did it with `efibootmgr`. I did some messing and I thought I re-ordered it but I must have deleted all of them. I'll find my laptop's model in a few minutes